# is there a plugin of jenkins can support job build periodically with specific script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Though in jenkins' job configuration I can control when job build using 'build periodically,but it only can appoint the build time.I hope this job will build according to different script at different time.Is there any suggestion ? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Script Trigger Plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin